# PHP undocumented imap_sort $search_criteria?

Tags: php, imap

PHP [imap_sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-sort.php) has an undocumented `$search_criteria` parameter. I'm writing a little script that should fetch mail containing a PIN code (five digits) in subject. Eventually not interested in any other mail. How can i specify my filter rule?

```
array imap_sort ( resource $imap_stream , int $criteria , int $reverse [, int
    $options = 0 [, string $search_criteria = NULL [, string $charset = NIL ]]] )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. It is documented. But obviously not at this function.

Better function for mail searching is [imap_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php) (it has documented $criteria). Search criteria is also defined in [RFC 1176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1176) (page 15 & 16).

Next thing is, that you cannot search with pattern, only string, so this will not work for you. I propose, that you fetch all e-mails, and compare subject that you need. You can limit your search by date...

Comment: That is... i don't need `imap_search` at all! Too bad. Thanks anyway.

Comment: how will you solve your problem with fetching only subjects with 5 digits?

Comment: Interating through headers and check subject prior to fetch the entire message.

Comment: So, at the end, you will select all mails... If this is kind a cronjob sciprt, and it is run once a day, you can use imap_search, and limit only 1day old emails. If you have big mailbox this is better.

Comment: Nope, should be an istant news publication service, that is the cron will run - say - every 10 minutes. How would you fetch only new mail in the last 20 minutes, for example? Can i filter using \\Seen flag?

Comment: If you have mailbox only for this e-mails, then you do not need to limit by day, just select all, and after viewing it, delete it, or move it to some label, away from inbox. But if you are using e-mail for other purposes, like info@ mailbox, then I would limit my search by date, one day back, like "SINCE 24-NOV-2011"; and again delete or store e-mail from inbox. I would not use Seen or Unseen, no need for that...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell [by looking at RFC5256] the `$search_criteria` parameter is likely related to the IMAP SEARCH command and probably uses the same syntax as the `imap_search()` function in PHP.

> The SORT command is a variant of SEARCH with sorting semantics for the
>   results.
>
> ...
>
> The SORT command first searches the mailbox for messages that match
>   the given searching criteria using the charset argument for the
>   interpretation of strings in the searching criteria.  It then returns
>   the matching messages in an untagged SORT response, sorted according
>   to one or more sort criteria.